# How to direct user to "rate our app" screen and to open rate dialog (without having them to click on Review)

Tags: android, app-store, rating, review, rate

We are trying to have our Android users rate your app. As we wish to send them a message through Intercom, we are only able to provide them a clickable link.

What we want is have them open up our app's page on the Google Play Store and have the Create a Rating dialog open up directly.
What we don't want (and have answers already on the web) is to take them to our app store page only.

We specifically want the Rate/Review dialog open up automatically / directly after they click the link. What type of link should be provided?

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Do you mind sharing if you solved this and/or the best URLs syntax that you were able to create to take your users to rate an app in the Google Play Store?   Different versions for PC and Android phone ?